# how write paper a single column with sajej

Tags: two-column, document-classes

I have a two-column document and I would like to change the format to single-column

I tried with

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh, times]{sagej}
```

but it does not appear to be working...

Comment: Have you tried the option `onecolumn`?

Comment: The documentation states that `Afour` correesponds to a two column layout while `Royal` or `Crown` correspond to single column.

Comment: @leandriis Where is the documentation? I tried `texdoc sagej` which came back with `sageep`.

Comment: @PeterWilson: I foulnd one here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/58d20eace243a8422cb2aff9/v/0/pdf?inline=true&name=SAGE%20LaTeX%20template

Comment: yes, i use this template  sharelatex.com/templates/58d20eace243a8422cb2aff9/v/0/…
▲but i want to change to one column

Comment: @JamalMRAZGUA: Do you want to submit to one of their journals? If so, just select the option that corresponds to the  journal you are submitting to.

Comment: As @leandriis said, use the `Royal` or `Crown` options. If you are not submitting to a Sage journal use whatever class, options, and packages that suit you.